# Using operators and logical commands correctly

Tags: r, statistics, mean, logical-operators

I have been asked to calculate the mean visits (to the doctor) for people within different age groups. I have calculated the mean for people aged less than 30 and people over 50.

```
mean(DoctorVisits$visits & DoctorVisits$age <30)
#[1] 0.07225434

mean(DoctorVisits$visits & DoctorVisits$age >50)
#[1] 0.1052023
```

However, I do not know how to calculate the mean of people aged between 30 and 50. Is this the correct formula or am I doing something wrong?

```
mean(DoctorVisits$visits & DoctorVisits$age>=30 & DoctorVisits$age<=50)
```

Comment: mean(DoctorVisits$visits[DoctorVisits$age>=30 & DoctorVisits$age<=50])

Comment: I don't think any of your examples work.  Have you tried an example, e.g. `DoctorVisits <- data.frame(age=c(10,35,45,60),visits=c(1,2,3,4))` and see if you get the expected results in each case?